# PHP://Input is Empty

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm messing around with writing a own bot for telegramm using hook.io to host the php script. The problem that I have is that file_get_contents("php://input") always seems to be empty, since the bot does not react if I try to do anything related to the update:

```
$updates = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input') ,true);

if($updates['ok']){

  //loop over all messages
  foreach($updates['result'] as $key => $value){
     if($value['message']['text']==="/test"){
       $chat_id =   $value['message']['chat']['id'];
       $result = file_get_contents( $apiURL . $apiToken . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=test');
     }
  }

}
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with this one?

Comment: are you trying to do POST on your backend ? If it's not a telegram's query php://input empty anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected in this way:

```
$updates = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input') ,true);

if($updates['update_id']){

 if($updates['message']['text']==="/test"){
   $chat_id =   $updates['message']['chat']['id'];
   $result = file_get_contents( $apiURL . $apiToken . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=test');
 }
}
```

the message is always one, so I deleted the foreach

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of that. Also I found out that Hook.io deletes the content of 'php:\\input' and pastes them into the $Hook array.